# Extremely hard function problem

Tags: functions

This problem was a question on a math test I took, and I didn't know how to solve it. How would you solve this?

Let 
$$f(x)=e^{-xe^{-\sqrt{x}}+e^{\sqrt{x}}}+2e^{xe^{-\sqrt{x}}+e^{\sqrt{x}}}.$$ Find $$f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(x)))))))))).$$

**EDIT**

For more convenience, the expression of $f(x)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \exp\bigl(-x\exp(-\sqrt{x}) + \exp(\sqrt{x})\bigr)+{} \\{}+ 2\exp(x\exp(-\sqrt{x}) + +\exp\bigl(\sqrt{x})\bigr).
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you work out what $f(f(x))$ was? If it doesn't collapse, nothing comes to my mind right now. Off hand, this looks like a question designed to test whether you were wise enough to skip to the next.

Comment: $f(f(0))$ is around $10^8$ and $f(f(f(0)))$ is too big for Maple.

Comment: @Lubin Are questions with the last purpose you stated intentionally designed in standard exams? If so I'm very surprised. It's the first time I'm hearing about a math exam testing for psychological skill.

Comment: Please give us the references of this math test.

Comment: Well, @Allawonder, this is not a standard question, either. Maybe it’s not to test psychological skill, but plain common sense.

Comment: @Lubin LOL, well. Mayhaps I don't have plain common sense. Because if I'd had extra time left I've tried everything I knew on that problem...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this somehow simplified to a hyperbolic trig function.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if this problem has a solution better then brutally computing the composition.

Comment: @GEdgar My CAS approximates it to $e^{4.948612527·10^{5061}}$

Comment: Observation: let $a=\exp(\sqrt{x})$.  Then $$f(x)=e^a\bigl(2\cosh(x/a)+e^{x/a}\bigr).$$